# How to use html tag for div, without ending div

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In this code I can just write **separate** div in every `Html::tag('div')` that as you know every `Html::tag('div')` means `<div></div>` .

But I want to put **a couple** div inside an specific div. bellow code could help you to understand it well.

```
$item[] = [
   'content' => [
           Html::tag('div', 'begin my div here',
               ['class' => 'background_white'] ), //<div class="background_white"> begin my div
           Html::tag('div', 'center'),
           Html::tag('div', 'end my div here,) //  end div my here </div>
   ]
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably try this :

```
$item[] = [
   'content' => [
           Html::tag('div', 'begin my div here' . Html::tag('div', 'center'),
               ['class' => 'background_white'] )
   ]
];
```

You could also look at `beginTag` and `endTag`.

Answer (score 2):

1) **div** inside another **div**

```
     $body[] = Html::tag('div','body',['class'=>'panel-body']);
     echo Html::tag('div',implode($body),['class'=>'panel panel-primary']);
```

2) **two** **div** inside **one** **div**

```
     $head[] = Html::tag('div','heading',['class'=>'panel-heading']);
     $body[] = Html::tag('div','body',['class'=>'panel-body']);
     echo Html::tag('div',implode($head).implode($body),['class'=>'panel panel-primary']);
```

Comment: It's good solution. but I think I cant use variable in my array.